# search single value in multiple fields codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I have to compare one values with multiple fields in single query using code-igniter.I have one value `$search_value` should match any of these two table fields `field 1` or `field 2` and a `$reference` number should match the `reference-number field`.

Query should match both reference number and search value.

My query:-

```
$this->db->where(array('reference_number'=>$reference_number,'field 1'=>$search_value));
$this->db->or_where(array('reference_number'=>$reference_number,'field 2'=>$search_value));
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like query to match your  `$search_value` in your field1 and filed2 and write `reference_number` in your where condition.

```
$this->db->like('field1', $search_value);
$this->db->or_like('field2', $search_value);
$this->db->where('reference_number', $reference_number);
$res = $this->db->get('TABLE_NAME');
```

**UPDATED**

```
 $this->db->where("reference_number=1234 AND field1='$search_value'");
 $this->db->or_where("reference_number=1234 AND field2='$search_value'");
 $res = $this->db->get('TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: `$this->db->like('field2', $search_value);` should be `$this->db->or_like('field2', $search_value);`

Comment: Reference number and field should be AND condition like select * from table WHERE reference_number= '1234' AND field1= $search_value. select * from table WHERE reference_number= '1234' AND field2= $search_value.The above query will not work for me.

Comment: @saty Thanks for the reply, the updated answer will search the value with field 1 only.. i need to search the $search value for both the fields field  1 and field 2, but along with the reference_number too (AND with reference_number)

Comment: am expecting a query like...  select * from table where reference_number=1234 AND field1=$search_value OR reference_number=1234 AND field2=$search_value.How to query this using codeigniter methods?

Comment: @saty The updated answer will AND all the conditions together..So this will not work.The search_value will match to one filed at a time (field1or field2), will not match for both fields.